# Spring utilizes websocket handler bean as singleton despite of it's prototype scope

Tags: java, spring-websocket

I face the problem trying to create a chat using Spring WebSockets.
Spring version - 4.3.1.
I created a class `ChatWebSocketHandler extending TextWebSocketHandler`. Here is the XML config for websockets:

```
<websocket:handlers>
    <websocket:mapping path="/websocket/chat" handler="chatWebSocketHandler" />
    <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor" />
    </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
</websocket:handlers>

<bean name="chatWebSocketHandler" class="org.kolokolov.chat.controller.ChatWebSocketHandler" scope="prototype" />
```

As you can see I defined the prototype scope for this bean.
Doing this I expected that Spring would create a new instance of ChatWebSocketHandler for any new user connecting to the chat. I need it because this bean is stateful as the UserProfile of the connected user is being written to it's field while connection establishing.
Here is the part of code

```
public class ChatWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
private UserProfile user;
private static final Map<String, WebSocketSession> connections = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@Autowired
MessageService messageService;

public static Map<String, WebSocketSession> getConnections() {
    return connections;
}

@Override
public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) throws Exception {
    this.user = (UserProfile) webSocketSession.getAttributes().get("user");
    connections.put(user.getNickname(), webSocketSession);
    String message = String.format("%s %s", user.getNickname(), "has joined.");
    broadcast(new Message(MessageType.MESSAGE, message, "[SERVER]").toJson());
    broadcast(new Message(MessageType.USER_LIST, getLoggedUsersList()).toJson());
    System.out.println(this + " : " + user.getNickname());
    System.out.println(connections);
}
```

Everything works fine for single user until I tried to connect second user to chat.
As far as I realized a new instance of `ChatWebSocketHandler` is not being created for new user. I added first `System.out.println` line to `afterConnectionEstablished` method to make sure of it.
And I have got this output for two users (Developer and Alex):

```
org.kolokolov.chat.controller.ChatWebSocketHandler@2c1b0d6d : Developer
org.kolokolov.chat.controller.ChatWebSocketHandler@2c1b0d6d : Alex
```

As you can see, looking at hash codes, the same instance of ChatWebSocketHandler is used for both users.
What should I take into consideration to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but still unanawered, so it will be good to handle it.

For the endpoint with the following code:

```
package com.my.company;

public class ChatWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    //override needed methods
}
```

There is a class org.springframework.web.socket.handler.PerConnectionWebSocketHandler which helps you achieve the goal of having one connection / instance of handler. XML configuration will be like:

```
<bean id="chatPerConnectionHandler" class="org.springframework.web.socket.handler.PerConnectionWebSocketHandler">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value type="java.lang.Class">com.my.company.ChatWebSocketHandler</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<websocket:handlers>
    <websocket:mapping path="/chat" handler="chatPerConnectionHandler" />
 <!-- your config here -->
</websocket:handlers>
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention and advice. It looks reasonable. But after I tried it, the issue is still there.
`org.kolokolov.chat.controller.ChatWebSocketHandler@641f80ef : User1`
`org.kolokolov.chat.controller.ChatWebSocketHandler@641f80ef : User2`